# Handler and Monads

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, servant

I'm struggling to compose [`Servant`](https://www.servant.dev/)'s [`Handler`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.16.2/docs/Servant-Server.html#t:Handler) and `Monad`:

```
class Monad p => Persist p where
  data Configuration p :: *
  runPersistance       :: Configuration p -> p a -> IO a
  initPersistence      :: p ()
  newKind              :: Kind -> p NewKindStatus
  -- ...

kind :: P.Persist p => KindUid -> KindBody -> p (Handler ())
kind (KindUid uid) (KindBody actions) = undefined

subject :: P.Persist p => KindUid -> SubjectUid -> EventData -> p (Handler EventUid)
subject kind subject body = undefined

event = post :<|> get
where post :: P.Persist p => KindUid -> SubjectUid -> Action -> EventData -> p (Handler EventUid)
        post kind subject action body = undefined
        get :: P.Persist p => KindUid -> SubjectUid -> p (Handler [Event])
        get kind subject = undefined

server :: P.Persist p => p (Server HermesAPI)
server = do
    k <- kind
    s <- subject
    e <- event
    return $ k :<|> s :<|> e

app :: P.Persist p => p (Application)
app = serve hermesAPI server
```

In order to answer to a route I have to use `P.Persist`, which is `Monad` doing `IO`.

I did not found a way to make `server` compile:

```
/app/Main.hs:55:3: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘KindUid
                        -> SubjectUid -> p0 (Handler [Event])’
                    with ‘(KindUid
                            -> SubjectUid -> Action -> EventData -> Handler EventUid)
                        :<|> (KindUid -> SubjectUid -> Handler [Event])’
    Expected type: p (Server HermesAPI)
        Actual type: p ((KindUid -> KindBody -> Handler ())
                        :<|> ((KindUid -> SubjectUid -> EventData -> Handler EventUid)
                            :<|> (KindUid -> SubjectUid -> p0 (Handler [Event]))))
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: k <- kind
    In the expression:
        do k <- kind
        s <- subject
        e <- event
        return $ k :<|> s :<|> e
    In an equation for ‘server’:
        server
            = do k <- kind
                s <- subject
                e <- event
                ....
   |
55 |   k <- kind
   |   ^^^^^^^^^

app/Main.hs:55:8: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘KindBody’ with ‘KindUid’
    Expected type: p (KindUid -> KindBody -> Handler ())
        Actual type: KindUid -> KindBody -> KindBody -> Handler ()
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: k <- kind
    In the expression:
        do k <- kind
        s <- subject
        e <- event
        return $ k :<|> s :<|> e
    In an equation for ‘server’:
        server
            = do k <- kind
                s <- subject
                e <- event
                ....
   |
55 |   k <- kind
   |        ^^^^
```

Since `Handler` is already a `newtype`, I'm stuck.
How can I compose `Handler` and my `Monad` in order to run it in Servant?

*Edit:*

I did a step thanks to *Mark Seemann*, lifting the `Handler` in order to leverage `ServerT`:

```
newtype LiftHandler p a = LiftHandler (p (Handler a))
server :: P.Persist p => ServerT HermesAPI (LiftHandler p)
server = LiftHandler kind :<|> LiftHandler subject :<|> LiftHandler event
```

Leading to:

```
app/Main.hs:55:22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘KindBody -> p2 (Handler ())’
                    with ‘Handler a2’
    Expected type: KindUid -> Handler a2
        Actual type: KindUid -> KindBody -> p2 (Handler ())
    • Probable cause: ‘kind’ is applied to too few arguments
        In the first argument of ‘LiftHandler’, namely ‘kind’
        In the first argument of ‘(:<|>)’, namely ‘LiftHandler kind’
        In the expression:
            LiftHandler kind :<|> LiftHandler subject :<|> LiftHandler event
   |
55 | server = LiftHandler kind :<|> LiftHandler subject :<|> LiftHandler event
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a sketch of a solution, but perhaps you'll find these hints useful. `Handler` is a `newtype` wrapper around `ExceptT ServerError IO a`, but sometimes, you may not be able to produce such a type directly.

However, if you have another `Monad` (like your `Persist`) you may be able to first define your API using that `Monad`, and then use `hoistServer` to translate to `ExceptT ServerError IO a`.

So, imagine, for example, that you define `server` with this type:

```
server :: ServerT API P.Persist
```

You should be able to transform it into a `Server` and run it like this:

```
run port $ serve api $ hoistServer api (Handler . trans) $ server
```

where `trans` is your transformation from `P.Persist` to `ExceptT ServerError IO`.

As [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server/docs/Servant-Server.html) of `hoistServer` says:

> Sometimes our cherished Handler monad isn't quite the type you'd like for your handlers.

I haven't tried to compile any of my code sketches, so there could be type errors. I don't know what `P.Persist` is, so I can't repro the issue.

You may alternatively want to define `server` as

```
server :: ServerT API (ExceptT ServantErr P.Persist)
```

so that you can use `throwError` to communicate HTTP (error) status codes. That might also make it easier to write the transformation from `ExceptT ServantErr P.Persist` to `ExceptT ServerError IO`, because now you just need to figure out how to transform `P.Persist` to `IO`.